# Jekyll internal server error only inside blog posts (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, jekyll

When I tell Jekyll to serve my site, everything goes fine, from the index to the other pages. But, when I click to see a blog post (any post), I started to see this message:

> Internal Server Error 
>   incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT 
>   WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.1.5/2014-11-13) at 127.0.0.1:4000

I'm running Jekyll on Ubuntu 15.10, and I'm trying to update this website: http://nvinhadeluz.com

EDIT ---

Here goes my _config.yml:

```
# Welcome to Jekyll!
#
# This config file is meant for settings that affect your whole blog, values
# which you are expected to set up once and rarely need to edit after that.
# For technical reasons, this file is *NOT* reloaded automatically when you use
# 'jekyll serve'. If you change this file, please restart the server process.

# Site settings
title: Núcleo de Promoção Humana Vinha de Luz
email: contato@nvinhadeluz.com
description: > # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
O Núcleo de Promoção Humana Vinha de Luz é uma entidade filantrópica que busca proporcionar o desenvolvimento humano e social na região em que atua. Guiados pelos princípios do Cristo à luz da Doutrina Espírita, desenvolvemos uma série de atividades religiosas e educacionais. Navegue pelo site e conheça um pouco mais do nosso trabalho!
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "http://nvinhadeluz.com" # the base hostname & protocol for your site
paginate: 3
paginate_path: "/blog/page:num/"

#Redes sociais
twitter_username:     Vinhadeluz1
facebook_username:    nucleovinhadeluz
instagram_username:   vinhadeluz
googleplus_username:  +Nvinhadeluzbh
youtube_username:     nucleovinhadeluz

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
gems: [jekyll-paginate]
exclude: ["Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock"]
encoding: UTF-8

# Default settings
defaults:
  -
   values:
     comments: true
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my site isn't in a public repository since it wasn't deployed at Github pages.

Answer (score 0):

My code examples:

Post example:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Copasa visita Centro Pedagógico Vinha de Luz!"
date:   2015-11-12 17:40:27 -0200
categories: Notícias
author: Júlio
image: copasa-visita.jpg
---
Hoje o Vinha de Luz recebeu uma visita da Copasa (Companhia de Sanemanto de Minas Gerais) para uma aula sobre o uso consciente da água, e adivinhem só? Nossas crianças sabem tudo sobre o bom uso dos nossos recursos naturais! Deram um show!

Confira as fotos na galeria abaixo, e logo mais há um vídeo das crianças cantando junto com os instrutores!
```

Posts layout:

```
---
layout: default
---

{% assign author = site.data.authors[page.author] %}

<div class="wrapper" style="max-width:700px;">

<article class="post" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

  <header class="post-header">
    <h3 class="post-title" itemprop="name headline" style="font-           weight:bold;">{{ page.title }}</h3>
    <p class="post-meta"><time datetime="{{ page.date | date_to_xmlschema }}" itemprop="datePublished">{{ page.date | date: "%b %-d, %Y" }}</time>{% if page.author %} • <span itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop="name">{{ author.name }}</span></span>{% endif %}
    {% include commentcount.html %}<!--Contador de comentários-->
    <span><a href="{{ page.url }}#disqus_thread"></a></span></p><!--Contador de Comentários-->
    <!-- Go to www.addthis.com/dashboard to customize your tools -->
    <div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
  </header>


  <img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/imagens/{{ page.image }}" style="margin-bottom:50px;">



  <div class="post-content" itemprop="articleBody">
    {{ content }}


  <div style="margin-top:50px;">{% include author-box.html %}</div>
  </div>

</article>

<div style="padding-bottom:50px;">{% include disqus.html disqus_identifier=page.disqus_identifier %}</div>

</div>
```

I didn't changed anything in Jekyll's core, and the bug started from nothing. Sorry if the code got a little messy, i'm still learning how to do things here.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand, have you managed to get your site up and running? Do you still need any help? :)

Comment: Yes, my site is up and running, on the web and in the internal server. BUT, on the internal server, when I click some post (anyone) I get the error I'm trying to describe.

Comment: Hmm, I got it! I'm pretty sure I've seen this error before on my PC too, and perhaps I'll be able to help you out. Which command are you using to serve Jekyll?

Comment: I run "sudo jekyll serve".

Comment: OK, I'll post an answer for you latter today, I'm not by my PC now. As soon as I get home I'll try to help you here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue must be related to one of Jekyll dependencies, so you'd need a dependency manager, like [Bundler](//bundler.io).

1. Install Bundler

   ```
   gem install bundler
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo gem install bundler
   ```
2. Add a Gemfile. Navigate to your project folder `cd path/to/folder` and run:

   ```
   bundle init
   ```

   This will create a Gemfile for you, like this:

   ```
   # A sample Gemfile
   source "https://rubygems.org"

   # gem "rails"
   ```
3. Edit your `Gemfile` in your code editor.

   If your site is hosted by GitHub, add this to your Gemfile:

   ```
   source "https://rubygems.org" # or replace https for http if don't have OpenSSL installed locally

   gem 'github-pages'
   gem 'jekyll-paginate'
   # any other gem you use in your project
   ```

   If you are not hosting your site on GitHub:

   ```
   source "https://rubygems.org"

   gem 'jekyll', '3.1.2' # or any other Jekyll version
   gem 'jekyll-paginate'
   # any other gem you use in your project
   ```
4. Run `bundle install`: this will handle all the `gems` you need and add a `Gemfile.lock` to your project folder.
5. On your `_config.yml` exclude `Gemfile` and  `Gemfile.lock` from builds:

   ```
   exclude: ["Gemfile", "Gemfile.lock"]
   ```
6. Serve Jekyll with Bundler:

   ```
   bundle exec jekyll serve
   ```

   You can add all the flags you want to this command, for example:

   ```
   bundle exec jekyll serve --watch -baseurl ""
   ```

Done!

One more thing: Portuguese has a lot of forbidden chars, so, every time you use things like `á` or `â` or `ã` in your Yaml front matter, make sure you do that between `""`:

```
categories: "Notícias"
author: "Júlio"
```

That's it! I think you should be ok then.

Let me know if this helped, yeah? :)

Comment: Bad news :/ Unfortunely it didn't work. I followed your instructions step by step and everything went fine. Served Jekyll by the command `bundle exec jekyll serve` and still having the same error when clicking some post. Also, I gave some attention to the portuguese special charaters adding some `"  "` in the front matters, but no good result.

Comment: Hmmm.. tha's sad. I forgot to say, did you add `sudo` before the commands? I believe you'll need it on Linux. Ok, let's go to our second option. The error seems to be related to AscII. Add `encoding: UTF-8` to your `_config.yml` and see what happens. And please edit your question and add the `_config.yml` content there, will be easier to see your configurations. Also, you could try to add `gem 'jekyll', '2.4.0'` to your `Gemfile`.

Comment: if any of this helps, try asking here: https://talk.jekyllrb.com/ You can talk  with Jekyll core developers directly.

Comment: Virtua, I'm getting worried here. None of this fixed the bug! Followed all the steps, got no errors, but still not able to preview a blog post inside Jekyll server. As asked, I edited my question with the config file. Also, I'll try to learn how to put my site at Github so you guys could see it and try to help. Anyway, thank you very much for the help you already gave me.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I made a brand new installation of Jekyll in a Virtual Machine and everything went just fine. Looks like I have a broken package or something. Jekyll is working perfectly again. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Great! But it's better always using bundler to build Jekyll site. Best of luck! :)